# PHP on NetBeans IDE

Tags: php, application

I have installed `netbeans` on my laptop running elementary os luna.
I installed `netbeans` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

After few minutes the software was successfully installed in my system.
But, when i try to create a new project, it shows only Java and PHP is not available there.
[image]
Now, how i can enable PHP here? Thanks

Comment: You can refer this: http://superuser.com/questions/204498/how-to-add-php-in-netbeans-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans is by default Java IDE, the fastes way is to remove your version of NetBeans with

```
sudo apt-get remove netbeans
```

and download netbeans with php bundle from [here](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html).

Then you can follow this [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/quickstart.html) for starters.

The other way is to install php bundle plugin from netbens itself but I don't now this IDE that well and I don't want to say something wrong.